# Download from external subversion repository and merge own code

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, svn-externals

My `project "A"` is in my own svn repository. My `project A` needs a reference to an external `project "B"`. But I need to modify the code of `project B`. I cannot commit code to `project B` since this is not my project. I want to checkout `project B` and merge code into `project B`.

What I have tried so far:

- Added `project B` as external link into a folder named `B_source`. (the update command downloads the external code. This step works)
- I copied with windows explorer the content of `B_source` into a folder named `B_changes` and applied the source code changes I needed. (works)
- I checked out `project B` into a folder named `B_patched`. (works)
- In TortoiseSVN right click on `B_patched`, click "merge", select "merge two different trees", set "From: B_source" and "To: B_changes" and "Working Copy: B_patched".
- "Test merge" showed the message **"svn/B_source path not found"**. I guess it's because of the external link!?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging is for taking two trees *in the same repository* and merging them to your working copy *from the same repository*. You would then commit that merge to the repository.

What you are trying to do, is apply custom changes to a repository, without being able to commit those changes. You cannot do this with the "merge" command.

What you're probably looking for is a [vendor branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html). The idea of a vendor branch is that you keep a project in *your* repository (call it "vendor") that you only update by copying unmodified code from the external project, and committing those updates. You create a branch of that project wherever you want (call it "patched") in a place convenient for you to pull into your build. You apply any of your custom changes to this branch. Periodically, as the external project makes updates, you will copy those updates into "vendor", commit, and then merge "vendor" to "patched" and commit those changes.

TortoiseSVN makes this easy with a context-menu entry when you right-click and drag from one unversioned folder into a folder in *your* repository which *you* maintain. You will not use svn:exterals in this case, you will simply be committing code, where most of the changes come from the customer.